# How can I find the number of occurences of a substring in a string in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a substring `'G^ATTC'` and I want to find the number of time it occurs in a string like `'ATCGCGATTC'` but I cannot because of `'^'`.

I used `re.findall`, but the result is always `0`.

Comment: May I ask, where does the `^` come from? And why don't you remove it?

Comment: Have you looked into `str.replace` to remove the characters that you don't want?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to find. If your substring is `'G^ATTC` and `'G^ATTC` doesn't occur why would a number other than zero be correct?

Comment: But `0` is correct. Or are you looking for occurrences of `GATTC`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Regex, the "^" character means "the start of the line." Related to this, "$" means "the end of a line"

So, when it's searching for "G^ATTC", it would never match anything, because you're saying the "G" comes before the start of the line (which doesn't even make sense).

The way to fix your regex is to include a "\" to escape the "^". This tells regex to treat the "^" as a character instead of the start of the line.

So, change it to "G\^ATTC"

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
import re

txt = "ATCGCG1ATTCAAAAAAAAAAAAAG4ATTC"
substring =  'G^ATTC'
x = re.findall(substring.replace('^','.'), txt) # ['G1ATTC', 'G4ATTC']
print ("pattern {} occurs {} times".format(substring,len(x)))
```

output:

```
pattern G^ATTC occurs 2 times
```